# SQL Server Pivot or Unpivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a table which basically needs to be transposed, and a new SUM column added to it (DaySum). The transposition won't include all the rows, but only the ones specified (from 17-01-02 to 17-01-08) as you can see below in the result table.

I have been trying different variations of Pivot and Unpivot, but I get the columns and values mixed up.

This is the table I'm trying to modify:

```
Date          User1   User2   User3
------------------------------------
17-01-01        1        0       1
Week1           0        1       0
17-01-02        1        0       1
17-01-03        1        0       1
17-01-04        1        1       1
17-01-05        1        0       0
17-01-06        1        0       0
17-01-07        1        0       0
17-01-08        1        1       0
Week2           3        0       2
```

The result should look like this:

```
Name    17-01-02  17-01-03  17-01-04  17-01-05  17-01-06  17-01-07  17-01-08  DaySum  Week2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
User1       1         1         1         1         1         1         1       7       3
User2       0         0         1         0         0         0         1       2       0
User3       1         1         1         0         0         0         0       3       2
```

I greatly appreciate your help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both.

You can use `CROSS APPLY` for unpivoting and aggregation for pivoting.

Something like this:

```
select 
    username,
    sum(case when date = '2017-01-01' then val end) [2017-01-01],
    sum(case when date = '2017-01-02' then val end) [2017-01-02],
    sum(case when date = '2017-01-03' then val end) [2017-01-03],
    sum(case when date = '2017-01-04' then val end) [2017-01-04],
    . . .
    sum(val) total
from (
    select t.date, x.username, x.val
    from your_table t
    cross apply (
        values  ('User1', User1),
                ('User2', User2),
                ('User3', User3)
    ) x (username, val)
) t
group by username;
```

Comment: Thanks GurV. Your answer did almost solve it. The total column sums all the values, giving a total of 11 for User1. The total should be 7.

Comment: @OscarDuran - That's because it's adding the week data too. You can adjust it to adapt your requirement

Comment: I'm not very experienced in this, and I have tried a few variations, but haven't got the total right so far. Would you be able to post whatever is missing so the right total would be displayed?